# Как обойти cloudflare при использовании aiohttp

Tags: python, парсер, aiohttp, cloudflare

Я новичок в использовании aiohttp и парсинге. Пытаюсь парсить сайт https://ssstik.io/ru , однако мешает cloudflare. Как мне обойти защиту cloudflare при использовании aiohttp?

Comment: Защита именно для того и существует, чтобы такие как вы не могли её обойти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте, мне помогло.

```
import asyncio
from aiocfscrape import CloudflareScraper

async def test_open_page(url):
    async with CloudflareScraper() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(test_open_page('<your url>'))
```

https://github.com/pavlodvornikov/aiocfscrape